# JavaBeans - getProperty to a variable

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

I create java class that include a list of users(called 'usersList' and include username and password for each value),

and now I create a JSP file and make scope of JavaBeans :

```
<jsp:useBean id="users"  scope = "page" class="Package.VoteDB"> </jsp:useBean>
<jsp:getProperty name="users" property="usersList"/>
```

I want to get the usersList to a variable , and then check if username:admin , and password admin include in this list. with the current code, it's just Print the usersList to the screen. how can I save it in variable (without printing the list to the screen) and check if it's include the admin user?

thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `<jsp:useBean>`'s `id` value, you can refer to the the bean and its properties with EL.

```
${users.userList}
```

As for

> check if it's include the admin user?

I wouldn't do this in a JSP. I would do it in a `Servlet`.